# DJANGO - AJAX request.files empty

Tags: python, ajax, django

This problem killed all my weekend so appreciate all the help i can get.

I have a form that upload reports by category. When submit form without ajax there is no problem. Bu when i switch to ajax, ajax doesn't send the file data to server.

`print(self.request.FILES)`

returns

```
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

This is html output of crispy form, so **enctype="multipart/form-data**" does exist.

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal my-2 mx-2" id="newReportForm" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**views.py**

```
class ProjectMainView(View):
    def get(self, request):    
        template_name = 'SiteMangement/index.html'
        form_class = newReportForm
        return render(self.request, template_name, {'form': form_class})  

    def post(self, request):
            if request.is_ajax():
                print(self.request.FILES)
                data = self.request.POST
                form = newReportForm(self.request.POST,self.request.FILES)     
                form.save(commit=False)

                if form.is_valid():
                    data = {'is_valid' : True}
                    form.save()
                else:
                    print(form.errors)
                    data = {'is_valid' : False, 'form_errors' : form.errors}

                return JsonResponse(data)
```

**my ajax post**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var newRepForm = $('#newReportForm');
        newRepForm.submit(function(event){
            $.ajax({       
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                  report_type :$('#id_report_type').val() ,
                  report_projects :$('#id_report_projects').val(),
                  report_date : $('#id_report_date').val(),
                  report_name:$('#id_report_name').val(),
                  report_file: $('#id_report_file').val()


},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').html("<p class='text-center text-success font-weight-bold'>Success</p>");


            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#message").html("<p class='text-center text-danger font-weight-bold'>Failed</p>");
            }
        });
          return false;
       });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File upload via AJAX is supported via [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Should be something like this

```
newRepForm.submit(function(event){
    var formData = new FormData(newRepForm[0]);
    $.ajax({   
       url: "",    
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
          $('#message').html("<p class='text-center text-success font-weight-bold'>Success</p>");
       },
       error: function(data) {
            $("#message").html("<p class='text-center text-danger font-weight-bold'>Failed</p>");
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```